# ¿Cómo obtener la posición seleccionada en un JSpinner?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Tengo un JSpinner que está rellenado con un array:

```
static String palabras[] = {"hola", "manzana", "leon", "castillo", "videojuego"};
static String words[] = {"hello", "apple", "lion", "castle", "videogame"};
```

Luego, cuando el usuario selecciona en los dos diferentes spinners alguna opción quiero comprobar si, en este caso, la traducción es correcta:

```
private void btnComprobarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
 if(palabras[0].equals("hola") && words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("hello")){
            lblResultado.setText("Correcto!");
        }
}
```

No conozco ninguna opción del spinner que deje comprobar que opción está seleccionada, algo equivalente al de android `spinner.getSelectedItem()`

Comment: @Aritzbn pero habla de java puro

Comment: Al tratarse de un simple array yo creo que podrías coger el index de los elementos seleccionados con un listener y al compararlossi tienen el mismo index es que es correcta (Teniendo en cuenta que los 2 estén ordenados es decir que hola y hello esten en la posición 0 de ambos)

String[] array = {"hola","manzana"};
Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("hola");

Comment: @MaQuiNa1995 si, están en orden a propósito, para facilitar la comparación

Comment: Pues con eso lo tendrías, ya nos dirás si conseguiste solventar tu duda

Comment: @MaQuiNa1995 si quieres poner la respuesta, no estoy entendiendo que tipo de listener controla el cambio en el spinner, el StateChanged serviria?

Comment: Alguien borró su comentario en el que venía lo del listener , ahora te lo pongo en la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que los arrays estén siempre ordenados:

Es decir¨:

```
String[] arrayCastellano= {"hola","manzana"};
String[] arrayIngles= {"hello","apple"};
```

Para ver si la selección es igual puedes coger las posiciones de los items seleccionados , esto lo puedes hacer con un listener que tendrás que poner a tus 2 spinners:

```
private int posCastellano;
private int posIngles;

spinnerCastellano.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        posCastellano = Arrays.asList(arrayCastellano).indexOf(spinner.getValue());
    }
});

spinnerIngles.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        posIngles = Arrays.asList(arrayIngles).indexOf(spinner.getValue());
    }
});
```

Ahora solo te faltaría ver donde quieres comprobar las posiciones (si al seleccionar el 2º spinner indiferentemente de cual se pulse, pulsando otro boton etc eso ya es cosa tuya solo habría que poner un if comparando las posiciones)

Para mas información sobre listeners en spinners puedes ir a esta pregunta de SO: [Listeners en Spinners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event)

Comment: estoy trabajando en java, de ahi que me salga el problema de que no existe ningún método de saber que item esta seleccionado, en java no existe el setOnItemSelected

Comment: ya edité la pregunta, espero que te sirva esa, al leer spinner me nublé la vista en android lo siento